# Calculating the execution time difference between 2 statements

Tags: java, time

What is the way to calculate time *(could be in shortest units)* between two steps in a running program ?

For example :

```
algo() {
  long time_1 = time_X
  .
  .
  .
  long time_2 = time_Y

  difference = time_2 - time_1;
}
```

I have been calculating using `new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()`. But the difference I get is `0`.

Is there any way I can know the difference between some steps in any algorithm ? Here I want to know the difference between the first and the last step of algorithm. Just before the algorithm will make a final return.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For milliseconds, use: `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead:

```
long time_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
.
.
.
 long time_2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and subtract. For nanosecond precision, use `nanoTime`. `nanoTime` is not related to any system clock other than an internal timer, so for 100 ns, it could go from 120 to 220, 100020 to 100120, etc, etc.

Comment: and why do I get `0` while using `Gregorian Calendar` ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta I wouldn't know, honestly. My guess is that you're taking a default instance that's identical to the next constructed.

Comment: Well, when you use calendar, you kinda get intrested only in minutes or seconds, the getMilisecond method is there only because of world wide convenction to measure time as miliseconds elapsed from 1.1.1970 (hope the date is correct)

Comment: @SuhailGupta It's important to note that there is a minimum granularity that the JVM can return, based on the operating system. I believe in Windows it is 5ms. The most common way to measure a algorithm is to measure multiple iterations through the code you want to benchmark. So you would create a timestamp, then run 1,000 iterations or whatever is appropriate, then get a completed timestamp. Once you have this, you can divide by iterations to get an average of the time per iteration.

Comment: @hexafraction No I am constructing a new instance each time

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
long time_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long time_2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
difference = time_1 - time_2;
System.out.println( difference + "milliseconds" );
```

Very useful for evaluating time taken by functions.  Also if you want to get time in seconds, divide the difference by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Guava's [Stopwatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) if you can use third party libraries. It can measure time with different granularity and helps in displaying the result in a well digestable format.

Answer (score 0):

[System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) is more precise than [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

That is what I use for my computation times when I need some.

Feel free to check the official Java API documentation for the details. To sum up :

**Advantages** :

- Time in nanoseconds
- Fairly precise to the millisecond

**Drawbacks** :

- Has a real meaning inside a single JVM runtime (don't compare nanoTimes between two different JRE or two separate invocations of the same JRE)